call stack stop while loading data loader
I am currently using VSCode with Anaconda. However, during training, the call stack process stops. This happens irregularly, sometimes with no errors during 100 epochs, and other times it occurs after just 10 epochs. The important thing is that no debug error appears in debug mode, and even trying to stop the code execution doesn't work.enter image description here. As shown in the picture, the training data is a 3D TIFF file.

I've already identified which part of the code is causing the issue. that is 334-line in the picture. enter image description here I've reinstalled Anaconda, PyTorch, the graphics driver, and CUDA, but the problem still occurs.

Please help.
I have reinstalled most of the libraries and programs, and also changed their versions. RAM, CPU, and GPU also did not show any significant issues.
